# getting Unsafe:javascript in anchor tag

Tags: javascript

I have built an anchor tag dynamically in javascript on a angular application. Am getting unsafe:javascript in front of the href attribute in the anchor tag and it inhibits the redirection. when i checked online there are suggestion touse $compileProvider but when i add that to the angular.module("app") angular is not working properly in the page. Please help or guide me how i can fix this.
my angular version is v1.5.8

My code:

```
(function () {

    var controllerId = 'UnitTracking';
    angular.module("app").controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$window', 'datacontext', 'config', 'spinner', UnitTracking]);
    function UnitTracking($scope, $window, datacontext, config, spinner) {

        $scope.init = function () {

        }
})();
```

Comment: It would help if you included that code which is generating the `a` tag.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use a link to run some JS by using a `javascript:` URL. Don't do that. Use a button and a proper event handler.

Comment: Sorry i thought i have shared the anchor tag code.Please find the code   var linkCellTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' +
                   '  <a id="link" class="text-blue-color text-underline" onclick="javascript:viewCPClaim(\'{{row.entity.TagNumber}}\');">{{row.entity.TagNumber}}</a>' +
                   '</div>';
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#link')).click();

Comment: I have tried the onclick attribute of the anchor tag . Its triggering but the problem is the expression (\'{{row.entity.TagNumber}}\') is not rendering and giving the value.

    var linkCellTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">' +
                   '  <a  class="text-blue-color text-underline" onclick="javascript:viewCPClaim(\'{{row.entity.TagNumber}}\');">{{row.entity.TagNumber}}</a>' +
                   '</div>';

when i use ng-click, the click event is not triggering but the expression(\'{{row.entity.TagNumber}}\')   is givng the value.